# jquery selector for buttons with same class and dynamic IDs

Tags: jquery

I've got a list of buttons with the same class and dynamic IDs. When user clicks the button, I want the text of that button to change to "Added". The rest of the function works fine, but the success result is not changing at all. Before I had the success result as:

```
$('.addalbum').text('Added');
```

but  it changed every button on the list to added. I only want the button to change that is next to the item that was selected. I'm trying to access the button's id in the selector, but no dice so far.

**jQuery**

```
$('.addalbum').click(function() {

        var album_id = $('.addalbum').attr('id');

        $.ajax({
                    url: '/album/addAlbumToList',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: data-is-here,
                    success: function (result) {
                        $('.addalbum' + album_id).text('Added');                    
                    }
                });
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

**HTML/PHP**

```
<button class="addalbum" id="add<?php echo $a->album_id; ?>">Add album</button>
so the IDs are #add123, #add124, etc.
```

Comment: It would be more interesting to see how the button and album is located in the HTML ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the click handler you can refer to the item itself using `$(this)`, so instead of this:

```
var album_id = $('.addalbum').attr('id');
```

You would write this:

```
var album_id = $(this).attr('id');
```

You could also create a variable for it, since you're using it in a few places:

```
var $album = $(this),
album_id = $album.attr('id');

// success handler
$album.text('Added');
```

*I'm using $album here to indicate it's a jQuery collection*

Answer (score 1):

You need `$(this).attr('id')` instead of `$('.addalbum')` when you are saving before ajax call.

```
$('.addalbum').click(function() {

        var album = $(this);

        $.ajax({
                    url: '/album/addAlbumToList',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: data-is-here,
                    success: function (result) {
                        album.text('Added');                    
                    }
                });
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: `album_id.text('Added');`? Did you mean `$("#" + album_id).text('Added');`

Comment: In your example `album_id` will be a string containing the ID. So calling `album_id.text('Added'); ` will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this` to refer to the clicked button.

```
$('.addalbum').click(function() {
    var button = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/album/addAlbumToList',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data-is-here,
        success: function (result) {
            button.text('Added');                    
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if the ID is unique why not

```
$('#' + album_id).text('Added');
```

Or better

```
$('.addalbum').click(function() {

        var thisbutton = $(this);

        $.ajax({
                    url: '/album/addAlbumToList',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: data-is-here,
                    success: function (result) {
                        thisbutton.text('Added');                    
                    }
                });
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume you've got confused. You're adding the album_id to the .addalbum, but the class, addalbum has no dynamic id, like you have in the field `id="add<?php echo $a->album_id; ?>"`
Probably this is why you're not getting it.